# If statement returning true when comparing user input vs sum of numbers

Tags: javascript, if-statement

Ok, so my project is to make a math quiz site. I have to have 2 numbers randomly generated and the user needs to fill in the number. The user needs to also needs to be able to choose their operation. Now my problem is under my second function I am trying to go by each operation and have the computed answer compared to the user input. As of right now my code either turns positive for all operations or depending on how many = I use it says sorry. I have tried adding another condition of if the add button is checked.

`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
    
    </head>

    <body>

        <h1><b>Pirate Math</b></h1>

        <p id= "bubble"><b>Ahoy Matey!</b> Can you help me practice my math?</p>
    
        <img id = "g1" src = "images/g1_t.png" alt= "Pirate Girl" height="200 px" width = "150px"/> 
    <ul>
        <li><p id = "num1"></p></li>

        <li><p id = "opBox"></p></li>

        <li><p id = "num2"></p></li>
    </ul>   
        <input type="number" id = "answerBox">
        
    <br>
    <br>
    
        <button id= "checkAns">Check Answer</button>


<br>
<br>
<br> 
        <fieldset>
            <h3>Choose your <br> operation!</h3>

                <input type="radio" id="op1" name="op" value="add">
                <label for="op1"> + </label>
            <br>
                <input type="radio" id="op2" name="op" value="sub">
                <label for="op2"> - </label>
            <br>
                <input type="radio" id="op3" name="op" value="mult">
                <label for="op3"> x </label>
            <br>    
                <input type="radio" id="op4" name="op" value="divide">
                <label for="op4"> &#xf7; </label>
         
            <br>
                <button id= "opPick">Click to pick!</button>
        </fieldset> 

<br>
        


        <p div class="copyright"><em><small>&copy; 2021 Ashley Kohn</small></em></div>



    <script>
        
        //button on click op choose
        document.getElementById("opPick").addEventListener("click", function operation(){
        
            var op1 = document.getElementById("op1");
            var op2 = document.getElementById("op2");
            var op3 = document.getElementById("op3");
            var op4 = document.getElementById("op4");

            console.log("op1 " + op1.checked);
            console.log("op2 " + op2.checked);
            console.log("op3 " + op3.checked);
            console.log("op4 " + op4.checked);

            //Addition 
            if ( op1.checked){
                var addNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                var addNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                
                console.log("this is with " + (Math.floor(addNum1) + 1));
                
                document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = addNum1;
                document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = addNum2;
                
                document.getElementById("opBox").innerHTML = "&#43;";
                
                
                var sum=0;
                sum=Number(addNum1)+Number(addNum2);
                console.log("SUM is: " + sum);
            }
        
            //subtraction
            if ( op2.checked){
                var subNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                var subNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                
                console.log("this is sub " + (Math.floor(subNum1) + 1));
                
                document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = subNum1;
                document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = subNum2;
                
                document.getElementById("opBox").innerHTML = "&#8722";
                
                
                var dif=0;
                dif=Number(subNum1)-Number(subNum2);
                console.log("DIF is: " + dif);
            }
            //multipulcation
            if ( op3.checked){
                var multNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                var multNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                
                console.log("this is with " + (Math.floor(multNum1) + 1));
                
                document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = multNum1;
                document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = multNum2;
                
                document.getElementById("opBox").innerHTML = "&#215;";
                
                
                var prod =0;
                prod=Number(multNum1)* Number(multNum2);
                console.log("PROd is: " + prod);
            }
            //division
            if ( op4.checked){
                var divideNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                var divideNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
                
                console.log("this is with divide " + (Math.floor(divideNum1) + 1));
                
                document.getElementById("num1").innerHTML = divideNum1; 
                document.getElementById("num2").innerHTML = divideNum2;

                document.getElementById("opBox").innerHTML = "&#247;";
                
                
                var divi=0;
                divi=Number(divideNum1)/ Number(divideNum2);
                console.log("DIVI is: " + divi);
                } // closing if
            }); // closing function 1
document.getElementById("checkAns").addEventListener("click", function math(){ // supposed to solve the addition
        
            var userNum = document.getElementById("answerBox").value;
            
            var addNum1 = document.getElementById("num1");
            var addNum2 = document.getElementById("num2");
            var sum = Number(addNum1) + Number(addNum2);
            var subNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
            var subNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
            var dif = Number(subNum1)-Number(subNum2);
            var multNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
            var multNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
            var prod = Number(multNum1)* Number(multNum2);
            var divideNum1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
            var divideNum2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (20 - 1 + 1));
            var divi = Number(divideNum1)/ Number(divideNum2);
            
            if (Number(sum) == Number(userNum)){
                
                    console.log("yay!");
        
                }//if statement closed
                
            /*else if (dif = Number(userNum) && op2.checked){
                
                    console.log("yay!");
        
                }//if statement closed
            else if (prod = Number(userNum) && op3.checked){
                
                    console.log("yay!");
        
                }//if statement closed
            else if (divi = Number(userNum)&& op4.checked){
                
                    console.log("yay!");
        
                }//if statement closed */

            else{
                console.log("sorry!");
                }
        })//closing function 2`
```

Comment: `addNum1` is an element, not the value. Use `addNum1.valueAsNumer` to get the value as a javascript number.

Comment: sorry this is only a portion of my code let me edit to add all of it

Comment: Please don't just code dump. Instead edit the question to make sure the code is a [mcve]

Answer (score -1):

`var addNum1 = document.getElementById("num1");` gets the element, you want the value inside.
Try `addNum1.value` to access the value. Currently it always evaluates to true because you are comparing two objects.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness